# React router redirect to a deeper url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm using react, redux, react-router v4, react-router-dom and react-router-redux. I have a problem that I wanted to append something to the current URL instead of replacing the current URL. The code is like this:

```
const App = () => (
  <div>
    <main>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/category/:categoryName" component={ProductList} />
        <Route path="/product/:productId/:infoType" component={ProductDetails} />
        <Redirect from='/product/:productId' to={`/product/:productId/details`}/>
        <Redirect from='/' to='/category/featured'/>
      </Switch>
    </main>
  </div>
)
```

for this line:

```
<Redirect from='/product/:productId' to={`/product/:productId/details`}/>
```

I want to append details to the current product url(eg. /product/1/details). But instead react router is redirecting to /product/:productId/details.

How can solve this issue? Any ideas? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Very late to this party, but you are passing the `to` property as a string literal (but with no expressions). Instead, you should use

```
to={`/product/${productID}/details`}
```

You'll need to store the query parameter in `productID`, of course. This will be contingent on how you are using Router - either grab the query param if available or assign productID however you see fit.